# What is the difference between the Big O and Big O star (asterisk) operator?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

I'm doing some research on algorithms complexity and in different papers I notice both the use of the regular Big-O operator `O(...)` and a variant `O*(...)`.

I never saw the definition of the latter one, which has an asterisk. I can't seem to find a definition anywhere. (Disclaimer: Googling for symbols is nearly impossible.)

What is the name and definition of the `O*(...)` operator? And how does it differ from the regular Big-O operator?

Comment: AFAIK, the $O^*$ notation means the polynomial factors are omitted.
I haven't seen a formal definition of it, but if I'd have to guess I'd say that it means something along the lines of $T(n)=O(p(n)\cdot c^{n})=O^*(c^{n})$, where $p(n)$ is a polynomial in $n$.
(If I'll find a formal definition to verify the above I will post it as an answer.)

Comment: It makes sense in the context of when I'm looking at. Thanks!

Comment: A paper which includes a definition of this notation: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X0700128X?via%3Dihub

Answer (score 11):

In parametrized algorithms, the algorithm gets an input $x$ and a parameter $k$.

The usual usage of $O^*(f(k))$ is saying there exists an algorithm which runs in time $$O(f(k)\cdot \text{poly}(|x|))$$

(e.g. $O^*(2^{2^k})$ means the algorithm is allowed to run in $O(2^{2^k}|x|^6)$, but not in $O(2^{2^k+k}+|x|)$)

This is somewhat different from the $\widetilde O$ notation for ``standard'' (non-parametric) algorithms which hides poly-logarithmic factors, i.e. 
$$O(2^nn^4)\subset\widetilde O(2^n)$$