# Is $O(n^k n!)$ in same complexity class as $O(n!)$?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

Can $O(n^k n!)$ be simplified to $O(n!)$, let's say for $k=2$?

Comment: No, because for any $C$, if $n^k>C$ then $n^k n!>Cn!$. You can say that $n^kn!\leq (n+k)!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. It may interest you to know the following fact: for any two functions $f, g: \mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{Z}^+$,
we have that
$$
O(f(n)) \text{ is the same as } O(g(n))
$$
if and only if there are constants $0 < c < C < \infty$ such that
$$
c \le \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \le C
$$
for all $n$ (or, for all sufficiently large $n$ is good enough).
In other words,
$\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ should be bounded and bounded away from zero. If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \in [0,\infty]$ exists, as will often be true in practice, this is equivalent to
$$
0 < \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < \infty.
$$

In our case,
$$
\frac{n^k n!}{n!} = n^k,
$$
which approaches $\infty$, so $O(n^k n!)$ and $O(n!)$ are not equivalent.

However, the difference between $n^k n!$ and $n!$ in e.g. complexity theory, is minimal; since $n!$ is so large, the $n^k$ hardly matters much in comparison. Formally, we could say that they differ only by a polynomial factor. In many contexts (complexity theory in particular, since you used the computational complexity tag), we choose to ignore polynomial factors.

Comment: So how can I safely argue that the algorithm runs in $O(n!)$? Do I need to explicitly qualify that the polynomial factor $n^k$ can be ignored?

Does the value of $k$ matter in this context? i.e. very high degree polynomial.

Comment: @MK If the algorithm runs in $O(n^k n!)$, you must say so, you cannot say it runs in $O(n!)$. I would say it is fine to either specify $k$, or just say that it is $n!$ times a polynomial factor.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot, as explained by another answer in this thread, but your intuition is correct that this is a useful way to think about the complexity.  The notion you are looking for is not $O()$ but $O^*()$: it is true that $$O^*(n!) = O^*(n^k\cdot n!)$$

when $k$ is a constant.  The idea is that one can say that $f(x)$ is in $O^*(g(x))$ whenever there is some polynomial function $p(x)$ such that $f(x)$ is in $O(p(x)\cdot g(x))$.  (I think this is not quite right, so please don't depend on it.)

I would like to refer you to a Wikipedia article that discusses this but I can't find one.  (Perhaps someone else can fix this?)  However, [What is the difference between the Big O and Big O star (asterisk) operator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672281/what-is-the-difference-between-the-big-o-and-big-o-star-asterisk-operator) discusses it a bit.